# How to import google spreadsheet into excel

Tags: excel, vba

Would you please help me with the folowing problem.
I'm using google form to colect data based on a google sheet. 
Now I'm looking to import these data in a local excel using "publish on web" method.
I don't have experience in excel. How I could define an automate process under excel to always read the data from the web address?

Thank you

Comment: This questin is liable to be **on hold** since requesting us to write all our code for the automatic process is considered too off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a link to test, but I suspect a generic web query will do the job for you.  Turn on the Macro recorder and import your spreadsheet data from the web, just like any other, similar, task.

```
Sub Basic_Web_Query()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah4Bis8FTYfCdDJILVdYOG1EZEYtc1N3NF96dHZSYkE&usp=sharing#gid=0", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1,2"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I manage to connect the data from google sheet with local excel using the link from the web page.

Comment: Ok.  Mark this answer as helpful, if it actually helped you resolve your issue.